# Socket Server with node.js socket.io , Can't connect to this server with using Quobject.SocketIoClientDotNet.Client in Visual Basic

Tags: node.js, vb.net, socket.io

Socket Server with node.js socket.io , I Can't connect to this server with using Quobject.SocketIoClientDotNet.Client in Visual Basic.

**node.js side**

```
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer();
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

// Handle a new socket connection
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('A client connected');

  // Handle a custom event
  socket.on('customEvent', (data) => {
    console.log('Received custom event:', data);

    // Emit a response event
    socket.emit('responseEvent', 'Server says hello!');
  });
 
  let plateImage = 'base64String';
    
  setTimeInterval(function() {
    socket.emit('ocrData' , {cameraId : 54 , plate : '06 AFA 749' , plateImage : imageBase64});
  } , 3000);

  // Handle disconnection
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('A client disconnected');
  });
});

// Start the server
const port = 3000;
server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

**Visual Basic Side**

```
Imports Quobject.SocketIoClientDotNet.Client
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim socket = IO.Socket("http://localhost:3000")

        ' Register event handlers
        socket.On(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, AddressOf OnConnect)
        socket.On(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT, AddressOf OnDisconnect)
        socket.On("responseEvent", AddressOf OnResponseEvent)

        ' Send a custom event to the server
        socket.Emit("customEvent", "Custom event data")

        ' Wait for input to keep the console application running
        Console.ReadLine()

        ' Disconnect from the server
        socket.Disconnect()
    End Sub

    Private Sub OnConnect(ByVal data As Object())
        Console.WriteLine("Connected to the server")
    End Sub

    Private Sub OnDisconnect(ByVal data As Object())
        Console.WriteLine("Disconnected from the server")
    End Sub

    Private Sub OnResponseEvent(ByVal data As Object)
        Console.WriteLine("Received response event: " & data)
    End Sub

    Private Sub HandleResponseEvent(ByVal response As String)
        ' Handle the response event from the server
        Console.WriteLine("Received response event: " & response)
    End Sub

    Private Sub HandleOcrData(ByVal data As Object)
        ' Handle the ocrData event from the server
        Dim cameraId As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(data("cameraId"))
        Dim plate As String = data("plate").ToString()
        Dim plateImage As String = data("plateImage").ToString()

        Console.WriteLine("Received OCR data:")
        Console.WriteLine("Camera ID: " & cameraId)
        Console.WriteLine("Plate: " & plate)
        Console.WriteLine("Plate Image: " & plateImage)
    End Sub

End Module
```

There isn't any movement in OnConnect , OnDisconnect , OnResponseEvent Action. I can't receive the data which is emitted node.js side. Can you help me about this issue ?

I try many things.But I can't fix the issue.

Comment: I use net instead of socket.io in node.js side. In visual basic side , I use TcpClient. It works.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22162617/connect-to-socket-io-using-vb-net/76377109#76377109